# Splitting number from its units

Tags: matlab, signals

I have a MATLAB cell array with following values:

```
'1mcg/kg'
'1mcg/kg'
'1mcg/kg'
'0.7mcg/kg/hr'
'0.7mcg/kg/hr'
'0.5mcg/kg/hr'
'0.5mcg/kg/hr'
'0.5mcg/kg/hr'
```

How do i split this into numbers and units? I need the output in two cell arrays something like:

```
'1' 'mcg/kg'
'1' 'mcg/kg'
'0.7' 'mcg/kg/hr'
'0.5' 'mcg/kg/hr'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp` to do this. We create a regular expression that matches the numeric portion in one group and the rest of the string in the other group.

```
out = regexp(data, '(\-?[0-9\.]*)(.*)', 'tokens', 'once');
out = cat(1, out{:})

%   '1'      'mcg/kg'   
%   '1'      'mcg/kg'   
%   '1'      'mcg/kg'   
%   '0.7'    'mcg/kg/hr'
%   '0.7'    'mcg/kg/hr'
%   '0.5'    'mcg/kg/hr'
%   '0.5'    'mcg/kg/hr'
%   '0.5'    'mcg/kg/hr'
```